# Need Help with PHP Uploading Image and PDF File Types

Tags: php, image, pdf, upload, file-type

How do I set the form restrictions in php to only allow jpgs and pdfs for upload?  Also, I seem to have an upload error when I set the file size to 800000.  Here is the upload form:

```
<form action="upload_files.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="img_preview">Preview Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="img_preview" id="img_preview" />
<br />
<label for="pdf_doc">Your PDF:</label>
<input type="file" name="pdf_doc" id="pdf_doc" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the upload_files.php

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["img_preview"]["size"] < 80000))
{
if ($_FILES["img_preview"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["img_preview"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["img_preview"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["img_preview"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
//check the file into its room
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_preview"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }
 else
 {
 echo "Invalid file";
 }
 ?>
```

This is the upload code for the img_preview file.  I would create another one for the pdf_doc file, but this one is not working right at the moment.

So, how do I increase the filesize limit to 8MB?  And, for the pdf upload I would like to restrict the file type to pdf, jpg, or gif.  So, I tried this as the parameters:

```
if ((($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "application/pdf"))
&& ($_FILES["img_preview"]["size"] < 80000))
```

but again errors.  What's the fix?  Is there a more fluid way to do this?

Comment: check whats exactly received by: print_r '<pre>'.$_FILES.'</pre>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### File type problem

Since the MIME type reported by the browser (which is what you get in `$_FILES`) can be spoofed, you can't rely on it. This leaves you with two reasonable options:

1. Filter by file extension
2. Filter using [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Unfortunately `finfo_file` is not included by default on PHP < 5.3, so this leaves you with the extension check (which has worked just fine for me in the past), or using the [discontinued PECL package finfo](http://pecl.php.net/package/fileinfo).

### Max upload size problem

There are *many* PHP settings that influence this, and you need to tweak *all* of them to have big uploads work. Fortunately, for some time now the PHP docs have [a page where everything related to file upload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) that can cause problems is discussed.